# How to change a VARCHAR column into Date format which already has string values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this column that contains `'NO RECORD'` values that I used to replace the `NULL` values and I want to change the column type into a  date but I get this message :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Of course, the reason behind it is the `No Record` values, so how I can keep the strings while changing the column into date, is that possible, because I want to fill my Null Values instead of keeping them empty

[image]

Comment: The real problem here is that you are storing date (and time) values as an `(n)varchar`; a fundamental design flaw. You should really fix your design here and use a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes).

Comment: To answer the question, I suggest looking at `TRY_CONVERT` for now; but fixing your design should be your next task.

Comment: It sounds like you should really be converting the type of this column to a nullable DATE (or DATETIME) and handling null values in whatever is reading the database rather than in the database itself. The database is meant to store data, not make it look pretty.

Comment: Replae the text with a default date, but  dates should always saved as dates

Comment: "how I can keep the strings while changing the column into date", you can't, and why would you want that? `NULL` in a `date` column would have the same meaning

Comment: *"the reason behind it is the No Record values"* - So update those to `NULL` first?

Comment: Add a new bit or int column `HasRecord`. Update your table to use this instead of text `No Record`. Create a new nullable date column with a temp name; parse and copy existing dates over. Remove current date column. Create a new date column with old name `Date_onset`. Copy date values over. Delete temp date column.

Comment: I suspect you may have a bogus date (beyond "No Record").  Try Select * from YourTable where try_convert(date,Date_Onset) is null and Date_Onset<>'No Record'

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You can use a case expression to capture the 'no record' values and not attempt to convert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your requirement is:

- Store a date (or datetime) value
- But, for a given row, you will not always have a known value
- When the data(time) is not available, show users "No Record"

In a relational database, this is best implemented with a column defined with an appropriate date/time datatype (date, datetime, datetimeoffset, whatever is most appropriate), with the column set as NULLable.

- When the value is known, store the value
- When the value is not known, store it as NULL

That accounts for data *storage*. How to *display* data to users is a different subject. No, really. Date/time data is not stored as a string of numbers and punctuation, it is stored in a very specific binary format. When the data is retrieved, it is formatted as the UI requires, even if that's only SSMS. After all, is September 10, 2011 displayed as

- 09/10/11   (US)
- 10/09/11   (UK)
- 11/09/10   (Sortable)

My point here is, if when the date(time) is not known you need to **show** the consumers of your data the string of characters "No Record", you will need to put in special handling on your UI to check to do this. An example:

```
SELECT isnull(date_onset, 'No Record')  date_onset
 from dbo.MyTable
```